# ImageView not showing Image - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have some code in Java fx controller class as below. The images are not showing up. Images are in place, no errors. Please guide.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    image1 = new Image(getClass().getResource("php81e3DF.png").toExternalForm());
    image2 = new Image(getClass().getResource("phpqJypee.png").toExternalForm());
    image3 = new Image(getClass().getResource("php2XSnrZ.png").toExternalForm());
    defaultt = new Image(getClass().getResource("phpxrxh4T.png").toExternalForm());

    imgVw1 = new ImageView();
    imgVw1.setX(200);
    imgVw1.setY(200);
    imgVw2 = new ImageView();
    imgVw3 = new ImageView();

    imgVw1.setImage(image1);
    imgVw2.setImage(image2);
    imgVw3.setImage(image3);
}
```

I am not able to make the images show up. I am sure the fxml and the controller class are using proper annotations. I used proper @fxml in the class and no errors with variables.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane fx:id="rootPane" alignment="TOP_CENTER" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <GridPane hgap="2.0" vgap="2.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <GridPane.margin>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
         </GridPane.margin>
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="imgVw1" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
            <ImageView fx:id="imgVw2" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <ImageView fx:id="imgVw3" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
            <Button fx:id="imageV1Button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#button1Pressed" text="Flip" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
            <Button fx:id="imageV2Button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#button1Pressed" text="Flip" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="CENTER" />
            <Button fx:id="imageV3Button" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#button1Pressed" text="Flip" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.valignment="TOP" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: If you have the appropriate `fx:id`s in the FXML file and the corresponding fields in the controller class, then remove the manual instantiation of the `ImageView`s. It is the responsibility of the `FXMLLoader` to create the objects and inject them into your controller; all you're doing is replacing those objects with other objects not linked to the visible scene graph.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add those lines of code:

```
imgVw1 = new ImageView();
imgVw2 = new ImageView();
imgVw3 = new ImageView();
```

What happens when you do this is:

1. `FXMLLoader` reads your FXML file to initialize the entire GridPane : `imgVw1`, `imgVw2`  and `imgVw3` are created and added to `rootPane`'s children list.
2. You define new values for `imgVw1`, `imgVw2`  and `imgVw3`, which means they no longer equal the value which has been defined into the FXML. So automatically, re-assignation makes your components disappear from `rootPane`'s children list, and none of your `ImageView`s will be displayed.

Deleting the 3 lines should solve your problem (at least it worked for me ☻).